# Angular 6 и get запрос google

Tags: angularjs, angular

есть проект на Angular 6 и необходимо сделать get-запрос на google.com
при это выводится данная ошибка `failed to load https://www.google.com/: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.` проект и скриншоты прилагаются по ссылке https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lI_02_nVXn8f0KLmUiyE9IPRZfemlGbi

Answer (score 0):

Если простыми словами: эта ошибка значит что гугл не разрешает крос-доменные запросы с домена http://localhost:4200
Более подробно о CORS 
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS